# Reference Component could not be found

Tags: c#, dll, reference, warnings

i'm trying to develop an application but then these warnings popped out. I have tried disabling my anti-virus (Avira) but it still won't work.

```
Warning 1   Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.    ConsoleApplication1

Warning 2   The referenced component 'MyAssembly' could not be found.
```

Can anybody please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Check your references. Did you delete a `MyAssembly.dll` that you referenced earlier?

Comment: No i didn't. Actually a friend gave me this dll which I can use for my application. I'm trying to add it to my solution by adding a reference. However, after adding it the warning messages pop out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What .NET runtime version is your application being developed with?

If the error is to be trusted, your project is say a .NET 3.5 (2.0 runtime) project but the MyAssembly library is developed in .NET 4.0 resulting in the error you see.

You cannot reference newer runtime version assemblies in an older runtime version project. You'd have to "upgrade" your project to at least match the framework version of the assembly given to you.

Right click on your project file and choose properties. Depending on what version of Visual Studio you are using this screen may look different, but go to the application tab and see what the target framework is.

[image: Project Properties]

Then go to the assembly you referenced in your references and check the "Runtime Version" in the properties section:

[image: Ref]

Comment: hi i tried this and the Target Framework shows me a list of three items in the dropdown namely: .NET Frameworks 2.0, 3.0, 3.5. Mine's currently using 3.5. I tried switching between these three and it still won't work. Does that mean I'll have to upgrade into .NET Framework 4.0?

Comment: Verify that your friends assembly is .NET 4.0 as mentioned above. If it is, then yes, the only way you could implement it is upgrading to a 4.0 project. If it's not a 4.0 assembly, something else is a afoot.

Comment: hi, i tried viewing the properties of my assembly and it shows a blank Runtime Version, and Path. Version it shows is 0.0.0.0. What the hell is wrong with my dll? :(

Comment: Next steps if it were me would be to attempt to load that DLL up in .NET Reflector, ILSpy, or DotPeek to verify the assembly is valid. If you can do that, I'd go that route, otherwise I'd talk to your friend to get the info you need.